# Overriding a dictionary Jinja template with payload

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a function that loads a Jinja template from a file, then applies a payload to set template variables.

```
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(output_dir), trim_blocks=True, lstrip_blocks=True)
template_file = os.path.basename(spec_file)
template = env.get_template(template_file)
jinja_file = template.render(payload)
```

***Example:***

File-content

```
Name: '{{NameID}}'
Age: 12
```

Payload:

```
{'NameID': 'Mugiwara No Luffy'}
```

Output:

```
Name: 'Mugiwara No Luffy'
Age: 12
```

I want to load the content from a dictionary instead of a file.

So we'll be loading a template from a dictionary and setting values from the payload.

**Troubleshooting:**

I tried to use the **jinja2.DictLoader** instead of the **FileSystemLoader**.

But still could not implement a proper solution for it.
I am a jinja2 lib beginner.

Can anyone help me in solving this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved using **jinja2.Template** :

*Steps:*

1. Convert the dictionary to a string
2. Create the jinja template
3. Render the result from the template using the payload
4. Convert the result back to a dictionary

**Code:**

```
ini_input = str(spec_dict)
template = jinja2.Template(ini_input)
result = template.render(payload)
final_wf = ast.literal_eval(result)
```